# Is MySQL a prerequisite for building HUE?

Tags: hadoop, hue

I'm trying to build hue and not having much success so far. I'm 
getting the following error message :

```
--- Building egg for MySQL-python-1.2.3c1 
sh: mysql_config: command not found 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 62, in 
run_setup 
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 105, 
in run 
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 64, in 
<lambda> 
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module> 
    metadata, options = get_config() 
  File "/Users/kramachandran/Sandbox/hue/hue/desktop/core/ext-py/MySQL- 
python-1.2.3c1/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config 
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r") 
  File "/Users/kramachandran/Sandbox/hue/hue/desktop/core/ext-py/MySQL- 
python-1.2.3c1/setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config 
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,)) 
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found 
make[2]: *** [/Users/kramachandran/Sandbox/hue/hue/desktop/core/build/ 
MySQL-python-1.2.3c1/egg.stamp] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [.recursive-env-install/core] Error 2
```

I'm interpreting this to mean that MySQL or MySQL python is a pre- 
req.  However, I don't see any documentation to that effect. 
Any information would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hue has the list of required packages for building it on the [README](https://github.com/cloudera/hue#development-prerequisites)

You will need the MySql dev packages, e.g. 'libmysqlclient-dev' with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Hue uses SQLite by default but can be configured to use MySql
see [the installation doc](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Hue+Installation#HueInstallation-TheHueDatabase)

Answer (score 0):

you need mysql_config do the following on your linux distribution, on centos the following will do:
yum install mariadb-devel

for 7.x, for others use apt with proper package.
once this is done you should be ok and it will continue building.